# heat energy and resistance of an elctric circuit

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

Very often it is said that "heat is developed" in a resistance when there is an electric current in it. But as far as I know heat is defined as a form of energy being transferred due to difference in temperature between two points. Now I am confused, is the statement inside the quotes technically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a charge Q is moved from one end of the terminal of a battery to another then there is an energy released in the form of kinetic energy of the electrons. This energy is ~VQ, where V is the voltage of the battery. The power which is energy per unit time is P=VI.

Now some of this energy could be lost in the wire, due to motion of electrons causing Jiggling of atoms, thus heating up the material. This effect solely depends on the properties of the material and this is precisely resistance. So when a current Is passed through a resistor, energy is spent in heating up the wire.

So you are correct in saying that Heat is a form of energy transferred due to temperature difference between 2 points. But that same concept is applicable in this context as the energy lost in the form of heating the wire.